# Integrate Unity3D with Vuforia into Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, unity-game-engine, vuforia

We have Cordova application that displays content from a back end CMS system and now client wants to implement Augmented Reality modeule to this application which is going to start after click on menu item in Cordova app.

We found a good way to do AR using Unity3D with Vuforia extension. Wikitude unfortunately does not support functionality that we need achieved in Unity.

Problem is that there is no plugin for Cordova that supports Unity project integration.

Is it possible to create plugin like that?

My idea: Export Unity project as Android project, make Cordova plugin with all the binaries Vuforia is using (is it possible?) and from Cordova app call Intent that opens Unity activity. Then do similar thing for iOS.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I am also looking for such solution but with wikitude plugin.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible to make this work. It is by no means trivial though. I've just released a Vuforia-based plugin for image recognition onto NPM and Cordova.

https://github.com/thisisbd/cordova-plugin-vuforia

It should be possible to build what you are looking for either on top of this or using this as an inspiration piece.

One thing I would say is that what you are looking at is a fairly large undertaking and should be treated as such. I'm hoping the cordova-plugin-vuforia repo will help you with what you are trying to achieve.